# Load Images in Directory in Sequence, Loading a Filler Image in Place of Missing Images

Tags: php, image

So i have a set of 20 images in a set, all labeled as dog. So dog01, dog02, dog03, etc. I'm using this code to pull those out of a directory and display them 5 to a row, in 4 rows like so.

```
dog01   dog02   dog03   dog04   dog05
dog06   dog07   dog08   dog09   dog10 (etc.)
```

I"m using this code to load the images from a directory, and it is loading them in order.

```
<?php
$dirname = "images/";
$images = glob($dirname."dog*.png");
foreach ($images as $i=>$image) {
$title = pathinfo($image);
echo '<img class="deck" src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $title['filename'].'" title="'.$title['filename'].'">';
if(($i+1)%5 == 0) echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

However, I want to see if there is a way to get it so that if one of the dogs is missing from the directory, it instead loads a filler in its place, and continues to load the others in sequence. So if dog03 is missing, it would look like this:

```
dog01   dog02   filler   dog04   dog05
```

It would show filler, and continue on the sequence. I'm genuinely not sure if I can achieve this in php. If someone knows what approach I need to take here, that would be appreciated. I should note that the filler image is in another directory called "fillers/".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of approaching this I think. The first is by not worrying about it in php, and loading the filler image as background image. Normally the image will be loaded over the filler image, but if the image does not load, the filler image stays visible.

The other way is by testing if the file exists.

**As background image:**

```
.deck {
  //whatever you had here
  background-image: url( "/filler/filler.png" );
}
```

You might need  to make container divs around your images, and put the css on that instead. Please note that if no explicit width or height is set, this will not work, as the background-image does not assign any width or height to the element it is attached to.

**By testing beforehand:**

```
<?php
$dirname = "images/";
$images = glob($dirname."dog*.png");
foreach ($images as $i=>$image) {
  if( file_exists( $image ) ) {
    $title = pathinfo($image);
    echo '<img class="deck" src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $title['filename'].'" title="'.$title['filename'].'">';
  } else {
    echo '<img class="deck filler" src="/filler/filler.png" alt="This image does not exist." title="This image does not exist.">';
  }
  if(($i+1)%5 == 0) echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

This method might not work if you are running php in safe mode.